# Joining tables across linked servers vs inserting into temp tables followed by joining in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

Say my end goal is to join tables from different servers in SQL Server 2019.
I've seen some posts on this and they outline how I must run the sp_addlinkedserver stored procedure which is relatively straightforward.

I'm wondering if this is **generally good practice** for data that isn't exceedingly large.
Say we have Database 1 (DB1) associated with Server 1 (S1) and Database 2 (DB2) associated with Server 2 (S2).

Then, is it better practice to insert tables needed from S2.DB2 into S1.DB1 as temp tables and join more "traditionally"?
As someone who is beginning to familiarize themselves with SQL, I'm wondering which would be widely considered as the better or more common action used by someone proficient in SQL. I ask this because deep down for some reason it feels 'risky' to join across servers even though it may not be.

Comment: The answer is, honestly, "it depends". Testing with both scenarios is likely the best option. Don't forget ou can index temporary tables too, and if you *are* "dragging" data from a linked server to a (temporary ) table locally, you may well want an *indexed* (temporary) table.

Comment: From what i noticed, sql server cannot perform a nested loop join on the fly across linked servers, so it needs to read the whole remote table in memory and then do a manual join. So if you join to a large remote table, this might be slow. But for smaller tables, i guess it matters less, and rather based on convenience. You can't create temp tables in views for example

Comment: Thank you both. Honestly these were the responses I was expecting but I was only asking in case my intuition was wrong and one was surely a better option in majority of cases.

Comment: Generally good practice is not to use Linked Servers in the first place, and to keep all data on one server, but obviously you don't have a choice.